# Extract XML content from a log file using Sed and dump each result to a different file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following 10 GB log file that I need to analyze directly on a Unix server.

```
2017-12-12 13:04:28,716 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message1
2017-12-12 13:04:28,716 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message2
2017-12-12 13:04:28,716 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message3
2017-12-12 13:04:28,716 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message4
2017-12-12 13:04:28,716 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message5
2017-12-12 13:04:28,732 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message6
2017-12-12 13:04:28,732 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG <xml>
<id>1</id> 
<!—- id is not unique since the XML data provides all the
information of an object X defined by its id at a specific point in time -->
some XML content on more than 500 lines
</xml>
2017-12-12 13:04:30,330 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message8
2017-12-12 13:04:30,333 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message9
2017-12-12 13:04:30,334 [ABC] [DEF] INFO some message10
2017-12-12 13:04:30,334 [ABC] [DEF] INFO some message11
2017-12-12 13:04:31,431 [ABC] [DEF] INFO some message12
2017-12-12 13:04:28,732 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG <xml>
<id>2</id>
some XML content on more than 500 lines 
</xml>
2017-12-12 13:04:31,432 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message13
2017-12-12 13:04:31,476 [ABC] [DEF] INFO some message14
2017-12-12 13:04:31,476 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message14
2017-12-12 13:04:31,490 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message15
2017-12-12 13:04:28,732 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG <xml>
<id>1</id>
some XML content on more than 500 lines 
</xml>
2017-12-12 13:04:31,491 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message16
2017-12-12 13:04:31,491 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message17
2017-12-12 13:04:31,496 [ABC] [DEF] DEBUG some message18
2017-12-12 13:04:31,996 [ABC] [DEF] INFO some message19
```

In order to do so, I would like to **extract each XML message and dump it in a separate file**.

**For example:** the first XML message would be stored in `file1.xml`, the second one in `file2.xml`, and so on.

If all the patterns had to be extracted to one single file, it would be quite direct with something like:

```
sed -n 's~<xml>(\s*\.*\s*)\s*</xml>~p' file.in > file.out #just a prototype
```

I thought about going to a solution in which I could use a back reference with the `<id>` tag of the XML and use it to name the file in which I would dump it, but it is not working since same values of `<id>` tag do appear at different places in the log file, which would overwrite the previous extractions.

```
sed -r 's~(<xml>…<id>(.*)</id>…</xml>)~echo "\1" >> \2.out~e' file.in #just a prototype
```

With `awk`, if the XML content was on one single line, it would be also quite straightforward. However, it is not the case and I don’t know which line separator I should define for `RS` to treat the XML content as if it was on a single line and dump it in separate files.

With `awk`, what I thought feasable was:

- first identifying the `<xml>` starting tag in the log and change a test variable to `yes`
- store each line of the XML in a buffer variable before dumping it to a `file$i.out` as soon as I get the `</xml>` (and of course resetting the test variable to `no`).

If you have a better solution with `awk` or a solution with `sed` in which I could access a variable containing the number of the pattern being currently treated and reuse it to generate the output files, it would be great. (something like that: `current_pattern_position` used to generate `file_$current_pattern_position.out`)

> **I got already pretty interesting solutions using `awk` and `perl`. I would like to have a `sed` working solution for this case**

Comment: Please be clear about this so no-one wastes their time posting something you don't want - do you **really** want a one-`sed`-script-only solution (like you have equivalent `awk` and `perl` solutions so far) or do you instead want a `bash` solution that uses possibly multiple `sed` calls plus other tools? If `sed`-only, should it be portable or can it be specific to one sed variant (e.g. GNU sed)?

Comment: Ideally 1 sed script solution, if not possible several calls can be used. GNU sed is fine :) Thank you for your help! Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Unless you want to do some contortions with GNU sed's `e` command, which eventually boils down to shoehorning a shell script into sed, I don't think you can write to multiple different files using a single sed invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Here's a portable, simplified approach using Sed:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

# Execute the following group of commands for each line in the XML node to
# generate a series of shell commands that we'll feed into an interpreter:
/<xml>/,/<\/xml>/ {
    # Extract the ID number to generate a command that changes the output file:
    /^<id>\([0-9]\+\)<\/id>$/ {
        # Using the same pattern as above, substitute the ID number into a
        # command that updates the current output file and increments a counter
        # for the ID that we'll append as the filename extension:
        s//c\1=$(( c\1 + 1 )); exec > "file\1.$c\1"/
        # Output the generated command:
        p
        # Then, proceed to the next line:
        n
    }
    # Output any remaining lines in the XML block except for the <xml> tags:
    /<xml>\|<\/xml>/ !{
        # Escape any single quotes in the XML content (so we can wrap it in a
        # shell command below):
        s/'/'"'"'/g
        #'# (...ignore or remove this line...)
        # Generate a command that will write the line to the current file:
        s/^.*$/echo '&'/
        # Output the generated command:
        p
    }
}
```

As we can see, the Sed program generates a series of shell commands from the input that we can pipe to a shell interpreter to write the output files:

```
$ sed -nf parse_log.sed < file.in | sh
```

This avoids excessive hold space buffering and GNU Sed's `e` flag which is painfully slow (we would need to spawn a child shell process every time we need to write a file), and enables us to efficiently track the number of times we encounter an ID so we can increment the number in the filename. Sed also includes a `w` flag that we can append to a pattern command to write a file more quickly (instead of shelling-out with `e`), but I'm not aware of any way to pass a variable argument to the flag.

Alternatively, we could include the contents of the program as an argument to Sed. Here's a squashed version that's easier to paste:

```
sed -n '/<xml>/,/<\/xml>/ {                             
    /^<id>\([0-9]\+\)<\/id>$/{s//c\1=$(( c\1 + 1 ));exec > "file\1.$c\1"/;p;n;}
    /<xml>\|<\/xml>/!{'"s/'/'\"'\"'/g;"'s/^.*$/echo '"'&'"'/;p;}                
}' < file.in | sh
```

It works, but we can probably tell that Sed isn't the best tool for this problem. Sed's simple language isn't designed for this kind of logic, so the code isn't pretty and we rely on the shell to generate the files, which adds a bit of overhead. If you're hard-set on using Sed, it may be okay for the job to take a little longer. For something performance-critical, consider using one of the tools described in the other answers.

Based on the information and examples in the question, I assume we don't want the opening and closing `<xml>` tags in the output, and the ID is always a number on its own line. The implementation writes filenames with a numeric extension that increments when it finds a duplicate ID (*fileID.count*, *file1.1*, *file1.2*, etc.). It should be easy enough to change these details if needed.

---

**Note:** If needed, the revision history contains the [two alternative implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48070098/7) (one using GNU Sed, and another that uses a wrapper script) that I removed for brevity. They work but are unnecessarily slow or complex.

Comment: This answer nails it, except that the OP noted that the `<id>`s weren't necessarily unique.  If that's so, the 2nd non-unique `<id>` would append what should be a 2nd file into the first with that `<id>` number.

Comment: @agc You're right! I misread the question and thought the OP wanted to group the output for each ID. I'll revisit this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer to address duplicate IDs and shell quoting. /cc @agc

Answer (score 3):

GNU **`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -v RS='<xml>|</xml>' '!(NR%2){ 
           gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, ""); 
           printf "<xml>\n%s\n</xml>\n",$0 > "file"++c".xml";
           close("file"c".xml")
       }' file
```

Viewing results:

```
$ head file*.xml
==> file1.xml <==
<xml>
<id>1</id> 
<!—- id is not unique since the xml data provides all the
information of an object X defined by its id at a specific point in time -->
some xml content on more than 500 lines
</xml>

==> file2.xml <==
<xml>
<id>2</id>
some xml content on more than 500 lines
</xml>

==> file3.xml <==
<xml>
<id>1</id>
some xml content on more than 500 lines
</xml>
```

Comment: By the way, do you think it's possible to do it with `sed`?

Comment: This accumulates open file descriptors which might be a problem after a 1020 or so (see `ulimit -n`) unique ids -- a `close("file"c".xml")` will solve that.

Answer (score 2):

perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'if(s/.*(?=<xml>)//){$x++;open$fh,">file$x.xml"}if($fh){print$fh $_}if(/<\/xml>/){close$fh;undef$fh}' input.txt
```

how it works

- `-n` : this is similar to `sed -n` will read input or argument files without printing
- `s/.*(?=<xml>)//` : to remove the left part before `<xml>` and evaluates to true if match

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way do you think it would be possible to do it with `sed`?

Comment: sed is not designed to write to multiple files apparently it can be done with gnu sed using `echo` + `>>` but it may be less optimal because opening file for each line, the same with awk. I think perl is more appropriate as the question stated _Any other sexy solutions using any unix commands/tools are of course welcome_

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `the same with awk` - awk is no less efficient at using output files than perl is and it certainly doesn't open an output file once per line.

Comment: indeed looking at system calls (strace) all the output files remain open with awk solution whereas in perl they can be closed explicitly

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'sub(/.*<xml>/,"<xml>") {out="file" ++i ".xml"; p=1}
     p {print > out}
     /<\/xml>/ {p=0; close(out)}
' file
```

In case of too many xml objects in the logs, you could get something like `error: Too many open files` so I add an optional `close` file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that is basically exactly what I proposed in the post :-)

Comment: "*extract each xml message and dump it in a separate file*"

Comment: With awk, what I thought feasable was:

fist identifying the starting tag in the log and change a test variable to yes
store each line of the xml in a buffer variable before dumping it to a file$i.out as soon as I get the (and of course resetting the test variable to no).　Anyway thanks :) :) :)

Comment: there is no buffering here. But yes this is the correct approach in general.

Comment: @Allan why would you want to use up memory buffering when you don't need to?

Comment: thanks, i added the modification. sub/gsub as conditions are nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, by the way do you think it would be possible to do it with `sed`?